# Can I change only the numbers in txt file?

Tags: c#, winforms, txt

Let's say I want to have a file with something like this
"
Milk 10
Bread 5
Eggs 6
"
I want to add a button or something that would allow me to input any numner to change only the number(price) on the one that I choose.
How can one do that?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to rewrite the file.

Comment: Read the file into `string`, e.g. `string text = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\myFile.txt");` then change `text` into required format; finally, save the `text` back to the file: `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\myFile.txt", text);`

Answer (score 0):

Regex will be the way to go:

For creating regex is: https://regex101.com/
to change 10 to 600
see code below:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"10";
        string substitution = @"600";
        string input = @"Milk 10 Bread 5 Eggs 6";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have missed a *little bit* in OP request: *"I want to add a button or something that would allow me to input any numner to change only the number(price) on the one that I choose"*. Though meta say [it's ok](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144452/299295).

Comment: Do you need Regex to replace `10` with `600`? The Op is not actually asking how to replace a piece of text with another, but how to write to a file only the part(s) that has/have being changed and not the whole thing. Not impossible, a binary file with fixed length *records* could do it. Kind of an IT Jurassic Park, though.